# C# Processing CSV file asynchronous with CSVHelper does not seem to work

Tags: c#, csv, blazor, blazor-server-side, csvhelper

I am creating a simple project with Blazor in C# where users can upload a CSV file and the app processes this file asynchronously to an object so that it can create a database record of this object.

I am getting stuck at processing the CSV file. I tried to process the CSV file myself first and this worked but read on several posts here that it would be wiser to use a library like CSVHelper. I am trying to use this library but it does not seem like it is doing anything and I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

I am using console.Writeline to check if anything is in the records collection but it seems empty.
Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong or what I am missing?

This is the page:

```
@using CsvHelper
@using System.Globalization
@using System.Text
@using CsvHelper.Configuration
@using CompanyName.Data
@using CompanyName.Services.CSV
@page "/uploadcsv"

<PageTitle>Upload CSV file</PageTitle>

<h1>Upload CSV file</h1>
<p>
    <label>
        Upload your CSV here:
        <InputFile OnChange="@LoadFile" multiple />
    </label>
</p>

@code {

    private async Task LoadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles())
        {
            var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                Delimiter = ";",
                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
            };
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
            {
                csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<OrderMap>();
                var records = csv.GetRecordsAsync<Order>();
                await foreach (var order in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(order.OrderNumber);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class that I use:

```
namespace CompanyName.Data;

    public class Order
    {
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string RecipientName { get; set; }
        public string RecipientStreet { get; set; }
        public string RecipientPostalCode { get; set; }
        public string RecipientCity { get; set; }
        public string CustomerNotes { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfCargo { get; set; }
        public int ShipmentQuantity { get; set; }
        public string? LocationId { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the classmap to map the CSV to the object:

```
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using CompanyName.Data;

namespace CompanyName.Services.CSV;

public sealed class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        Map(o => o.OrderNumber).Name("ActivityId");
        Map(o => o.RecipientName).Name("LocationName");
        Map(o => o.RecipientStreet).Name("LocationStreet");
        Map(o => o.RecipientPostalCode).Name("LocationPostalCode");
        Map(o => o.RecipientCity).Name("LocationCity");
        Map(o => o.CustomerNotes).Name("ActivityNotes");
        Map(o => o.TypeOfCargo).Name("ShipmentTypeOfCargo");
        Map(o => o.ShipmentQuantity).Name("ShipmentQuantity");
        Map(o => o.LocationId).Ignore();
    }
}
```

## Update

I have tried altering it to a synchronous flow (private void LoadFile with
`csv.GetRecords<Order>()` and without using await) and this results in the same exception that I found when debugging the async task only now it immediately shows this when uploading the CSV. This is the stacktrace:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Synchronous reads are not supported.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Span`1 userBuffer, Boolean& readToUserBuffer)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadSpan(Span`1 buffer)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at CsvHelper.CsvParser.Read()
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.Read()
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.GetRecords[T]()+MoveNext()
   at CompanyNameLogistics.Pages.UploadCSV.LoadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e) in C:\Users\User\Documents\CompanyNameLogistics\CompanyNameLogistics\Pages\UploadCSV.razor:line 33`
```

Comment: See if you have any errors (Dev-Tools, console)

Comment: Console does not show anything unfortunately. When I am debugging and I place a breakpoint at: using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config)). When I hover over the reader it shows an exception at the EndOfStream: System.NotSupportedException: Synchronous reads are not supported.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.get_EndOfStream()

Comment: It is the server side version of Blazor, not web assembly.

Comment: That gives me more errors.

Comment: Probably not. The file I am trying to read is around 5kb.

Comment: I think you may be hitting the problem from [Never returns when using GetRecordsAsync #1751](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1751#issuecomment-1158984745).  From the comment by MaxBrooks114: *Edit 2: I believe I found the issue. If this is happening to you when reading a memory stream directly from a blazor file input (such as was the case with me), it will cause significant memory issues. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server) The Getrecordsasync method works fine after this.*

Comment: That being said, you do have one problem, namely that `StreamReader` does not implement `IAsyncDisposable` and so will dispose the stream returned by `file.OpenReadStream()` synchronously, causing the *System.NotSupportedException: Synchronous reads are not supported.* you mentioned in comments.  Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p5OnPS.  Instead, tell the StreamReader to leave the stream open, and dispose it yourself with an `await using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())` then `using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, leaveOpen : true))`.  Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KPmiXi

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion about leaving the stream open (see below). This did not work yet but I will look at the other suggestions tomorrow! Thanks!

await using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, leaveOpen : true)) 
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))

Answer (score 2):

I think you have encountered a bug in the CsvHelper library. "dbc" pointed to issue #1751 in the CsvHelper repo, and I believe you are experiencing the same issue, which is a deadlock caused by async code that doesn't call `ConfigureAwait(false)`. You can read about the details of that [here]:(https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)

This issue happens when the code runs under a SynchronizationContext, which it appears is the case for Blazor server, as well as in windows GUI applications.

I opened a pull request which should fix this issue, though you would also need to `ConfigureAwait(false)` all of your async invocations:
https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/pull/2007

In the mean time, you can pull and build the "configureawait" branch at: https://github.com/MarkPflug/CsvHelper/

That should at least allow you to answer if this will fix your issue.

**Update**

The proposed [pull](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/pull/2007) was [committed](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/commit/bc60b088f7fa1e4d49e37fc477de47beceef0c60) as of CsvHelper version [29.0.0](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log/#section-2):

> Missing `ConfigureAwait(false)` added to async calls.

Comment: Interesting!  Would doing `var records = csv.GetRecordsAsync<Order>().ConfigureAwait(false);` (like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CuPaa6)) resolve the problem?

Comment: I tried that in my test app and it didn't fix it. I had to add ConfigureAwait(false) to all the CsvHelper calls as well. I was testing under the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext, the blazor one might behave differently, but I suspect it will also deadlock.

Comment: I will try to see if this works tomorrow. I'll let you know and for now thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an async method, but not awaiting the results. Change this:

```
var records = csv.GetRecordsAsync<Order>();
```

To this:

```
var records = await csv.GetRecordsAsync<Order>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. This method with type System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable is not awaitable.

Comment: @IdodeJong it is awaitable (in a foreach or so)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around my issue by copying the browserfile and writing it into a project folder and then opening this local file into a new filestream and feeding that into a readstream which is then processed by CSVHelper.

Not sure if this is the right approach and it probably goes against the advice of Microsoft of taking the entire file into memory but since I only use very small files in this use case it should not be much of a problem.

Since I am a beginner please respond if I can make this more efficiënt or if there is a better way to do this. Happy to take some feedback! Otherwise thanks for all the help!

This is the code I used. I did use a new (smaller) class (OrderTest) with less properties and a new mapper (CsvOrderTestMapping) just for figuring this out so it does not entirely match with my code in the original post.

```
@code {

    private async Task LoadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles())
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"TempFiles\", file.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(path);

            await using (FileStream fsWrite = new(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fsWrite);
            }
            var configuration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                Encoding  = Encoding.UTF8,
                Delimiter = ";",
            };
            await using(var fsRead = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(fsRead, Encoding.UTF8))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, configuration))
                {
                    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CsvOrderTestMapping>();
                    var data = csv.GetRecordsAsync<OrderTest>();
                    await foreach (var order in data)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(order.RecipientName+ ",  " + order.RecipientStreet+ ", " + order.OrderNumber);
                    }
                }
            }
            File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
}
```